# What happens with the number of edges and degrees of the vertices in a graph with $\gamma (G)=4$?

Tags: graph-theory

If the domination number of a planar graph $G$ is $\gamma (G)=4$. If $G$ has $n$ vertices, what can we say about the number of edges and degrees of the vertices of $G$ ? For example, if $\gamma (G)=1$ we could say that it is a complete graph and thus the degree of the vertices is $n-1$. Thanks.

Comment: $\gamma(G)=1$ just says that there is a vertex that is adjacent to all of the other vertices. That doesn't imply that the graph is complete. The path on three vertices has $\gamma=1$, for instance.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DominationNumber.html has some results, e.g., $\gamma\ge n/(1+\Delta)$, where $\Delta$ is the maximum vertex degree, and $\gamma\le n/2$ if there are no isolated vertices. That page also gives many links to the literature.

Comment: Was that of any use?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, thanks for the Wolfram link. It was very informative and I liked a lot the table with different kinds of graphs. Very nice material!